# convergence of sequence of functions on an infinite interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $n\ge 1$, Let $$g_n(x)=\sin^2(x+\frac{1}{n}), x\in[0,\infty)$$ and $$f_n(x)=\ \int_{0}^{x}g_n(t)dt$$. Then

1) $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to a funtion $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ but does not converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$

2) $\{f_n\}$ does not converge pointwise  to any function on $[0,\infty)$

3) $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$

4) $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

i found the pointwise limit of $g_n(x)$ then I don't know how to solve.

Comment: what did you get for the pointwise limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$f_n(x) = \int_0^x\sin^2\left(t+\frac1{n}\right)\,dt=\int_0^x \frac1{2}\left[1-\cos\left(2t+\frac{2}{n}\right)\right]\,dt$$

Then consider bounding $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ using the inequality $|\sin a - \sin b|\leqslant |a-b|.$

Comment: can you tell me, which one is the right answer?

Comment: Sure. After integrating we see that the limit is $f(x) = x/2 - (1/4)\sin(2x)$.  Did you get that part?

Comment: Then $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = (1/4)| \sin(2x + 2/n) - \sin(2x) - \sin(2/n)| \leqslant (1/4)|\sin(2x + 2/n) - \sin(2x)| + (1/4)|\sin(2/n)| = O(1/n)$ for $x \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Limit function is continuous, but it doesn't imply that sequence is uniformly convergent, so what we should do next?

Comment: So it appears the sequence converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: i don't know the meaning of $O(\frac{1}{n})$ can you explain?

Comment: $|\sin(2x+2/n) - \sin(2x)| \leqslant |2x + 2/n - 2x| = 2/n$ and $|\sin(2/n)| \leqslant 2/n$.  So $|f_n(x)- f(x)| \leqslant 1/n$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$.  Then

Comment: Thank you. Now It is clear . One more thing that tell me about that notation, I would also like to use that in future

Comment: Well we did not need it, but big-Oh has the following meaning:  $f(n) = O(g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$ if $f(n)/g(n)$ is bounded for large $n$.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry this is last question. can you suggest a book of Real analysis in which i can found examples handling such a problems also which cover other topics like series, R-integration, metric space etc.?

Comment: Just look at any book covering asymptotics to learn the definitions of $O$, $o$, and $\sim$.

Comment: Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin, Mathematical Analysis by Apostol, and Real Analysis by Bartle are the basic references.  If you want to delve deeply into sequences and series with many examples look at the classics Theory of Infinite Series by Bromwich and Theory of ... Series by Knopp.